# How to configure styles in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

Does someone have a proper guide to configure styles in CKEditor please? **My objective** is to customise the dropdown list (I only really need one dropdown) to provide multiple styles of the same HTML tag. For example a `P` tag could have the following styles: `<p>`, `<p class="excerpt">`, `<p class="highlight">` that can be selected from the dropdown list.

I tried to read this [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles) but it has a lot of missing information. It uses a lot of CKEditor jargon and doesn't give an overview of the architecture or execution/initialisation pipeline to begin with.

I am using a very simple CKEditor (below) and I cannot find the difference between the "Paragraph" and "Normal" dropdown.

[image]

The documentation says use this code to configure toolbar:

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];
```

I see "styles" in one of the code lines, but it does not explain what "name" is, and what `{ name: styles' }` does. Removing it will remove both the dropdowns and there is no hint in how to customize the dropdown list.

Then I found

```
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
```

but this only allows me to remove the dropdown item, not the combobox itself.

There is also the `CKEDITOR.styleSet.add`

```
 CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [
    // Block-level styles
    { name: 'Blue Title', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': 'Blue' } },
    { name: 'Red Title' , element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },

    // Inline styles
    { name: 'CSS Style', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my_style' } },
    { name: 'Marker: Yellow', element: 'span', styles: { 'background-color': 'Yellow' } }
] );
```

Again, it does not explain where to place this code, or the execution sequence in the initialization pipeline. It does not explain how the value 'my_style' is used, whether it is a reference to some other configuration. I also don't quite understand the purpose of the comments "block level styles" and "inline styles". Seems irrelevant? The configuration code does not seem to make a distinct between these 2.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor', {
 height: 500, 
 contentsCss: '.helloworld { background-color:#C0C0C0;}.helloworld2 { background-color:#5555C0;}',
 docType: '<!DOCTYPE HTML>',
toolbar: [
  { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
{ name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
{ name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
{ name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', ] },
{ name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
{ name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles'  ] },
{ name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
{ name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
{ name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
  ],
stylesSet: [
    { name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'helloworld' } },
    { name: 'Paragraph2', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'helloworld2' } },
  
]
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zf9w6tmm/5/